# How to choose second and third element (li) in <ul> tag (with CSS)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I have this code to select my first, second and third li tag, but i was asking myself if it was possible to write this code shorter. I usually don't use the child() selector so I don't know much about it.

```
ul > :first-child{
    margin-right: 50px;
}

ul > :first-child + li{
    margin-right: 50px;
}

ul > :first-child + li + li{
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chain two `:nth-child()` pseudoclasses to match a range of adjacent elements:

```
li:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

this will select both the second and the third `li`
acting like the logical `and` operator.

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOpapY)

---

Visual result of the effect of these psuedoclasses chained:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but i don't understand "(n+2)" and "(-n+3)". What if i want to select my first, second and third li tag and not the fourth?

Comment: the draw I just posted might give you an hint. If not, just change `n+2` with `n+1` (or simply omit the first pseudoclass). in this example `2` and `3` are respectively the lower and the upper bound

Comment: Why do not you only use nth-child(1), nth-child(2) etc.?

Comment: Because if you need to select a larger range of elements (e.g 1-4) that way would result in a longer declaration.

Comment: I've bene using nth-of-type for years (and nth-child) and had no idea you could use it twice to get an intersection. Also: great artwork :)

Answer (score 5):

For second child you can use

```
li:nth-child(2){}
```

and for third child use

```
li:nth-child(3){}
```

Comment: This is easy to use, but it's just copy paste work so i prefer to use something shorter :) Thank you anyway

Answer (score 3):

CSS has a `:nth-child` selector just for that. You can do something like this :

```
ul > li:nth-child(3){ ... }
```

Read more about this at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: Thank you, and how can I for example select the first, second and third li tag at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are correct. Summed up, your code would look like:

```
ul > li:first-child {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

ul > li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 50px;
}

ul > li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but i found something shorter than this :D 
Thanks to @fcalderan i have this code:
`
li:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+3) {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
`

Comment: Does this only affect the first three elements, or will it also affect i.e. the sixth element? @NedimKurt